# Is the set $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{73}) \in {\Bbb R}^{73} \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 = 1\}$ compact in $\Bbb R^{73}$?

Tags: general-topology

Given $l^2$ = {($x_n$) |  $\sum_{n=1}^∞ x_n^2 < ∞$}

My attempt so far:

I can intuitively understand that {($x_n$) ∈ $l^2$ |  $\sum_{n=1}^k x_n^2 < 1$} where k is fixed will not be compact. This is because for n > k i might find a constant sequence of some sort which shows that it is unbounded and hence not compact. But this is dealing with Hilbert spaces while I have only studied till approximation theorems in my semester so far, so unsure about how to move forward with the proof.

Comment: Your title is asking about $\Bbb R^{73}$, and your question body is asking about $l^2\subseteq \Bbb R^\infty$. Which is it, really?

Comment: The function $f(x_1,\dots,x_{73})=\sum_{n=1}^{73}x_n^2$ from $R^{73}$ to $R$ is a continuous polynomial function and your set is (if i understand correctly) $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ which is closed because it is the preimage of a closed set by a continuous function. Also your set is bounded: none of the coordinates can have absolute value greater than one. Closed and bounded --> complact. It is the boundary of the 73-dim sphere centered at the origin

Comment: The set {($x_n$) ∈ $l^2$ |  $\sum_{n=1}^k x_n^2 < ∞$} is trivially the whole of $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no infinite sum in your set $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{73}) \in {\Bbb R}^{73} \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 = 1\}$, as you're working in *finite-dimensional* space. This allows the argument that the set is closed and bounded and hence compact by the Heine-Borel theorem which applies in any $\Bbb R^n$ with finite $n$.